# Geometric brownian motion - Ito's lemma

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have a question about geometric brownian motion. dS = uSdt + /sigma/*S*dW and then we do log(S) and we want to found dlog(S). So we use Ito's lemma en I get the dt part of the lemma but I don't see why df/dt*dw is zero.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

If $f(t,S) = \log(S)$ then $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,S) = 0$, since $f$ does not depend on $t$. Is this what you're asking?

Using Itô's formula, you will get

\begin{align}
d\log(S_t) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,S_t)\,dt +\frac{\partial}{\partial S}f(t,S_t)\,dS_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial S^2}f(t,S)\,(dS_t)^2\\
&= 0\,dt + \frac{1}{S_t}\,dS_t - \frac{1}{2S_t^2}\,(dS_t)^2\\
&= \Bigl(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\Bigr)\,dt + \sigma\,dW_t
\end{align}

Comment: But S does depend on t, so don't we use the chain rule?

Comment: @user1200276 Ito's formula *is* the chain rule, appropriately modified for Ito stochastic integration. Indeed the first two terms in the first line are exactly what you would expect from the classical chain rule. The last term is the special term for stochastic equations.

Comment: @cimrg.joe I think you made a whole bunch of calculation errors. In particular I don't think there should be any $t$'s in the denominator, and that the $dW_t$ in the first line should be $dt$.

Comment: I found me error. Thanks for the help Joe.

Comment: @Ian, you are correct.

Comment: @Ian you are absolutely correct. There are just so many errors. Haha. Sorry for that.

Comment: They should be corrected now.